# There is no external storage in "Device File Explorer"

Tags: android-studio, upload, gallery, android-sdcard

I created an **AVD** with **Sdcard** with **2GB** capacity in **android studio**. I need to upload my files in **Sdcard**(Not Internal that is name Sdcard)  but there is no Sdcard in **"Device File Explorer"**, There is just only **internal memory** with name "**Sdcard"** . I tried to upload my files to **internal storage** and move them to **sdcard** in next step but none of those files doesnt show in **gallery** and this solution it's **not** worked for me, Even I tried **"Media Provider"** in **"Dev Tools"** but Dev Tools crashes after clicking on "Scan Sdcard" Button. My app needs to load files using **"MediaStore"** and if images & videos on **Sdcard** are exists they wiil **not** load in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another **avd** again and **sdcard** showed up.
But to load images & videos from sdcard in **gallery**, I have to **eject &  mount**  sdcard on changing sdcard content **every time**